# How to trigger an external visitor my website?

Tags: web-services, web, authentication, scheduled-tasks

I am using an app machine, in the free license the app will sleep in one hour if there are no users (than it will take 1 minute to wake up, stupid rule anyway). So I want to solve this by developing an internal/external scheduled task.

I tried to schedule an event for each 58 minuts and update the statistics but it didnt work. The app machine sees there are not external users apparently.

So...How can I solve this? Would an external web service for login work?

Hope to hear frm you
thnx

Comment: What do you want to request? a web-site? open an app at an mobile device?

Comment: Hi. it is a website. If an external visitor just visit the website each 58 minuts it will be okay.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for that.

Try to use a proxy requesting your website because it could be that the ip is logged and the visit does not count:

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://school-proxy.net/browse.php?u=https://www.google.com' );
curl_exec( $curl_handle ); // Execute the request
curl_close( $curl_handle );
```

Please have the proxy-url `http://school-proxy.net/browse.php?u=https://www.google.com` in mind and change it to your url.

If `curl` does not work, you could try to use [`file_get_contents($url)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) if `allow_url_fopen` is set to `1` in your `php.ini`.